# Conditionally manage a mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I have a query where I am getting the count of students. Now, I want to modify that query and manage it conditionally.
Here is my query

```
SELECT count(students.id) AS student_count,
FROM students
LEFT JOIN students_admission ON students_admission.student_id = students.id
WHERE student_gender='Male'
AND students.address = 'Address'
GROUP BY id
```

This is what i want

```
$admission_date = null;

SELECT count(students.id) AS student_count,
FROM students
LEFT JOIN students_admission ON students_admission.student_id = students.id
WHERE student_gender='Male'
AND students.address = 'Address'
AND students_admission.admission_date = '$admission_date'
GROUP BY id
```

But, i want to add 
`AND students_admission.admission_date = 'admission_date'`
this condition only when $admission_date is not null. So, I tried this

```
SELECT count(students.id) AS student_count,
FROM students
LEFT JOIN students_admission ON students_admission.student_id = students.id
WHERE student_gender='Male'
AND students.address = 'Address'
CASE WHEN '$admission_date' IS NOT NULL THEN students_admission.admission_date = '$admission_date' END
GROUP BY id
```

which returns a syntax error. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use boolean logic:

```
AND (
    :admission_date IS NULL 
    OR students_admission.admission_date = :admission_date
)
```

You can also phrase this as:

```
students_admission.admission_date = coalesce(:admission_date, students_admission.admission_date)
```

Note that you should be use parameterized queries rather than mungling string variables into the query string: this is both more efficient and safer (your current code is widely exposed to SQL injection). See [this famous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/10676716) for the whys and hows.

Also, please note that putting conditions on the `left join`ed table in the `where` clause of the query actually turns the `left join` to an `inner join`. You probably want this condition in the `on` clause of the `join` instead.

Comment: i declared $admission_date variable on the top. Sometimes, this variable has a value or sometimes this variable is set to null. I don't want to run AND condition when the value of a variable is set to null.